# read write excel file on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, libraries

I would like to know your libraries recommendations to read and write Excel applications on ASP .NET website.

I have tried GemBox and NPOI, because they don't required Excel to be installed on the server, but they have some limitations on handling Excel files that are marked to read only.

Any good and stable libraries that you recomend

Comment: "limitations on handling Excel files that are marked to read only" - could you elaborate on this, please?

Comment: If you try to open Excel file that have any kind of password in your excel, for open or for change, you will not be able to use GemBox. I have tried and receive a message saying: 'file is not a valid OLE2 Compound File ....'

Comment: The recent versions of GemBox.Spreadsheet support any password protection on the XLSX file and workbook or worksheet protection on the XLS file. Also, you can even detect if the file is encrypted with `XlsxLoadOptions.IsEncrypted` static method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx).

Best Library I know.

Comment: Passed 1º test. Lets try a harder one

Comment: 2º test passed, but it's very expensive

Answer (score 4):

OpenXml and Syncfusion XlsIO

HTH

Answer (score 3):

[SyncFusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition) is pretty stable.  I've never used them in an ASP.NET app, but I've used their controls in WinForms apps, and they are supposed to be safe for ASP.NET.

It's not free, though.

Answer (score 2):

As David suggested,  may be you could try Syncfusion XlsIO,  they seem to have a seperate method to read and process readonly excel files.

http://help.syncfusion.com/ug_83/Reporting/XlsIO/ASP.NET/default.htm?turl=Documents%2Fworkbook.htm

Answer (score 1):

OpenXML SDK for xlsx files
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, but because I need to open encrypted files. OpenXML is not an option